# small vbs with finishing touches help, .CLOSE SAVECHANGES:=False

Tags: excel, pdf, vbscript

Creating a vbscript to open a .csv file, run a macro and print to pdf.   With the help of "the internet" i have been succesful.   Time for a little clean up and thats where I need your help!

I am running the following VBS

```
    Option Explicit
    Dim xlApp, xlBook 
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    '~~> Excel File Path
    Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\AppFiles\06.2013.csv", 0, True)
    '~~> Excel Macro location and Name
    xlApp.Run "PERSONAL.XLSB!Auto"
    xlBook.Close 
    xlApp.Quit 
    Set xlBook = Nothing
    Set xlApp = Nothing
    WScript.Echo "Finished."
    WScript.Quit
```

As mentioned, it gets the job done.  HOwever,  I would like for the "Do you wish to save" prompt by excel to be automatically answered as NO.   I have attempted to add the savechanges:=False to to xlBook.Close so that it looks like this:   xlBlook.Close savechanges:=False   This gives me the Expected Statement 800A0400 error..

Second, I would like to send a command to close the PDF file.  If that is possible.   I do have an additional application running while this is going on, so a mass window close command is not possible.  The PDF does seem to be highlighted, if there is a close highlighted window command..

I have searched and searched and tried and tried!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a line `xlBook.Saved = True` before closing the workbook:

```
...
xlApp.Run "PERSONAL.XLSB!Auto"
xlBook.Saved = True
xlBook.Close
...
```

Comment: That worked for the Auto Save button.   Any suggestions for closing the PDF?

Comment: The `Auto` macro is best placed to close the pdf, or you could convert the code in the `Auto` macro to run from your VBScript.

Comment: @jason. Without knowing how the PDF is actually opened, there's not much I could suggest.

Comment: It appears the PDF is being opened through the excel macro while preforming the print function.   The macro is saving the PDF with the current date,  perhaps there is a way i can have it print without opening or close after printing.

Comment: @jason. Please show the macro. We're not sitting in front of your computer.

Comment: I Was able to close the PDF by editing the Macro.  So in my face.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `Close` method should also work with

```
xlBook.Close False
```

because VBScript doesn't recognise the argument-name `SaveChanges`, but it will recognise it as this argument because of its position (the first argument).